# How to create user without giving him Admin role for Internal Testing in iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

How can I add Tester for Internal Testing. In the help window there is a message:

> Internal testers can use the TestFlight app to install new test builds
>   for any of your apps. Only 25 iTunes Connect users with the Admin,
>   Technical, or Legal role can be added as internal testers.

So I'm trying to create user but there is no such role like "Technical" or "Legal". I don't want to make my Internal Testers "Admin" (It's only available role from description above) because Admin can even enable/disable testing and can change marketing settings for the app.
Take a look at the screen below. Only those role are available so the question is which one to choose right now? How You guys handle Internal Testing?[image]

Comment: Look at my answer below. I hope it will help You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've contacted with Apple and this is what I get after several mails with explaining everything.

> The iTunes Connect Technical role is no longer supported. It’s been
>   replaced with the App Manager and Developer role.
>
> Each of these roles are available for internal TestFlight Beta
>   Testing, and a list of role provisions and responsibilities are listed
>   when you select the role for the new users.
>
> It’s at your discretion to determine the best role setting for your
>   testers to suit your individual business needs.
>
> Again, I sincerely apologize any confusion. Please let me know if
>   there’s anything else I can do for you.

So just create a user with Developer role solved the problem but this was not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

With new rules, `Admin`, `Application Manager` and  `Developer` could be used for "Internal Beta Testers".